# Set asp:PlaceHolder visible to true with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Does anyone know how can I set the `asp:PlaceHolder` visible from `false` to `true` with jQuery?

I have the following code to hide a table:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhSignatureProcess" runat="server" Visible="false">

  <div class="cl_interactions">
  <h1><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSignatureProcess" Text="" /></h1>
    <table border="0" class="cl_form_table" >

      <tr>
        <th valign="top" width="85"><span style="color:Red;">*</span>Signature Process Opt In?</th>
        <td>
          <span style="color:Gray;font-size:12px;">Yes</span><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="btnOptInYes" CssClass="btnOptInYes"/>
          <span style="color:Gray;font-size:12px;">No</span><asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="btnOptInNo" CssClass="btnOptInNo"/><span id="opt_err" style="color:Red;font-size:10px;display:none;"> required</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top" width="85">Signature followup date</th>      
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dtSignatureFollowUp" Text=""/><span id="dtSignatureFollowUp_err" style="color:Red;font-size:10px;display:none;"></span><br/><span class="info">(Date format: dd/mm/yyyy)</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top" width="85">Signature priority customer</th>      
        <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSignaturePriority"/></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Any way I could visible this asp:PlaceHolder by using jquery?

Comment: No, visible=false on an asp.net control means the markup for placeholder won't be rendered on the client

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET placeholder doesn't render any HTML at all, it's purely intended for containing other controls. If you want to show or hide a container-type control using jQuery, use a DIV (or an ASP.NET Panel) or some other container.

Also, remember the ID will be augmented by the framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss(v=vs.100).aspx - so you'll need to use a class selector in jQuery, or set `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.